i have implemented kong proxy-cache plugin globally and want to purge cache when try to purge cache at admin-api/proxy-cache gives me 404 error
admin-api/proxy-cache/cacheid
gives me 404 error
It should work according to documentation.
I am using free version of kong and
following kong documentation to purge cache we have endpoint admin-api/proxy-cache/cacheid
which is not working also getting proxy-cache/cacheid also not working.

Are you targeting the right host port ?
